# Use xargs and grep to find information within files

Tags: bash, awk, grep, xargs

I have this directory of other directories

```
$ ls
fish dog cow bird sheep
```

inside each of those folders I have different files

```
$ ls cat/
A11 A12 B11 B12 C11 C12 D11 D12
```

I then query each direcotry for `FARM`, I get a list, which I parse, to remove the full path and only keep the concerned root directories, after `awk` I get `cow sheep`, and I want to now look into those folders to see those that live on `land`.

```
$ grep -l "FARM" */A1* | awk -F/ '{print $1}' | xargs -0 -I {} grep "LAND" {}/B*2
```

This won't work,

```
cow
sheep
/B*2: File name too long
```

Comment: Question edited. I thought it was clear my query fails. @anubhava

Comment: You're not feeding null-terminated strings to xargs, just ordinary lines.  strip the `-0` from its options.

Comment: @jthill doesn't solve issue

Comment: When I'm having trouble with a pipe, I like to sprinkle `echo`s and `tee`s on it.  They're like pixie dust.  Try putting a `tee` stage in there, or `echo`ing the commands you're constructing.

Comment: Your question isn't that clear - are you trying to search within only the B*2 files for LAND? `grep -l "FARM" */A1* | awk -F/ '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} grep -R "LAND" {}` will find these results, but also the results in other files below "cow" or "sheep"

Comment: @kmassada, re: jthill's advice, just because something isn't the *only* thing you need to do to solve a problem doesn't mean it isn't still a thing you need to do to solve the problem. Using `xargs -0` with an input stream that isn't NUL-delimited will never work.

Comment: @kmassada, ...could you extend this question to include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Having code that sets up the environment needed to run your command, and then provides both actual and intended results, would both clarify the question and allow folks to actually test their answers. (In this case, a MCVE might be a script others can run that creates a temporary directory with your sample files, and greps for content within those files). As it is, it's very hard to be certain that a given understanding of the problem is the correct.

Answer (score 3):

To use `find`, `grep` and `xargs` (on a system with extensions `-print0` and `-0`) you could use

```
find "$path" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -e "$what_to_look_for" /dev/null
```

The usage of `-print0` in `find`, and `-0` in `xargs` forces the use of the NUL character (which can't exist in a filename) as a delimiter, so filenames with spaces, tabs, or even newlines work as well. The `/dev/null` ensures that there are always at least two arguments passed to `grep`, so it prints filenames corresponding with matches even if `find` only locates a single file; if you were guaranteed to always have GNU find, you could take out the `/dev/null` and use `-H` for this purpose.

For example:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 grep -e FARM /dev/null
```

---

To work with pure POSIX find (for the 2006 revision of the specification or later), you could also avoid needing to use `xargs` at all by using the `-exec` argument to `find`:

```
find . -exec grep -e FARM /dev/null '{}' +
```

Comment: Eh? `-print0` is a `find` operator, not a `grep` operator (for widely-available implementations).

Comment: And you might as well use `find . -exec grep -e FARM /dev/null {} +` and get `xargs` out of the way in the first place.

Comment: Charles Duffys suggestion is IMO a better solution, the -exec param allows to avoid the use of xargs. Please go ahead and edit away my proposal.

Comment: Sure!!! Great answer, thanks for your edits, they really added value to the answer.